# ckeditor применить ко всем textarea на странице

Tags: ckeditor, textarea

Как ckeditor применить ко всем textarea на странице.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('.editor').each(function(e){
        CKEDITOR.replace( this.id, { customConfig: '/path/to/config.js' });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<textarea class="editor"></textarea>
<textarea class="editor"></textarea>
```

Comment: Смысл понятен. А нетли стандартной функции редактора для этого?

Comment: Замените `.editor` селектор на `textarea`. Далее происходит итерация по элементам и через стандартную функцию редактора инициализируется.

Answer (score 2):

```
CKEDITOR.replaceAll( );
// Всетаки пришлось поковыряться в доках :)
```

Comment: http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/themedui.html#CKEDITOR-method-replaceAll исходя из исходников делает тот же replace, однако в моем примере можно воспользоваться селектором на свое усмотрение :)